# How to record jmeter script with fiddler

Tags: json, jmeter, blazemeter

I am in a phase of mobile performance testing. I am trying to record script from mobile device with jmeter but unable to do it, then I tried recording using blazemeter but I observe that is not recording the contents properly. I capture the request in fiddler and the contents gets recording. I like to know how can I convert that request into .jmx file.